# Server & client-side TypeScript project organization, compilation

Tags: typescript, webpack

How can I compile my TypeScript project what

- Shares code between server & client
- Uses TypeScript

I couldn't get webpack working, the website just shows a very basic getting started. I tried gulp, but it was far too complex and the incremental compilation took a very long time (way more than it should need).

```
src/
    common/
        data.ts
        [other files that are needed on both client and server-side]
    server/
        server.ts
        search.ts
    client/
        sw.ts
        resources/
             [other static resources like index.html]
[configuration files like package.json]
```

How can I do it? What should I use?

**EDIT:**

With gulp, I used gulp-typescript and tsify but the incremental compilation took more than 5 seconds, which was way too much.

Comment: Would you please post your tsconfig?

Comment: Is there any reason why you're not using `tsc`?

Comment: Because client-side need something like tsify

Answer (score 4):

I use npm scripts to start 3 "watch" processes:

- One that watches the client files (webpack) and compiles then into a folder called `public`.
- One that watches the server files (tsc) and compiles then into a folder called `private`
- One that watches the output server code (nodemon) and runs the node.js app when it changes.

Both apps can import files from `common` ans it should work fine.

My `scripts` config in `package.json` looks as follows:

```
  "scripts": {
    "watch-all": "npm run watch-server & npm run watch-client & nodemon --inspect private/server.js",
    "watch-server": "tsc -p tsconfig.json -inlineSourceMap -outDir private --watch",
    "watch-client": "webpack --watch",
  }
```

We have multiple standalone apps inside "client" and each app uses a folder. So we use webpack to create one bundle for each app.

My webpack config looks as follows (Note: there are some plugins that you may not need in this config):

```
const { CheckerPlugin, TsConfigPathsPlugin } = require("awesome-typescript-loader");
const Visualizer = require("webpack-visualizer-plugin");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");
const TypedocWebpackPlugin = require("typedoc-webpack-plugin");

const corePlugins = [
    new CheckerPlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        "process.env.NODE_ENV": JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV || "development")
    }),
    new Visualizer({
        filename: "./debug/statistics.html"
    }),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
        // ...
    ])
];

const devPlugins = [
    new TypedocWebpackPlugin(
        {
            name: "ORG",
            out: "../private/docs",
            mode: "file",
            tsconfig: "./tsconfig.json"
        },
        "./src"
    )
];

const prodPlugins = [
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
];

const plugins = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? corePlugins.concat(prodPlugins) : corePlugins.concat(devPlugins)

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        "app1/": "./src/client/app1/index.ts",
        "app2/": "./src/client/app2/index.ts",
        // ...
    },
    devServer: {
        inline: true
    },
    output: {
        filename: "[name]bundle.js",
        path: __dirname + "/public",
        publicPath: "/public"
    },
    devtool: "source-map",
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".webpack.js", ".web.js", ".ts", ".tsx", ".js"],
        plugins: [
            new TsConfigPathsPlugin({ configFileName: "tsconfig.json" })
        ]
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                enforce: "pre",
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: "source-map-loader",
                exclude: [ /node_modules/, /experimental/ ]
            },
            {
                enforce: "pre",
                test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
                loader: "tslint-loader",
                exclude: [ /node_modules/, /experimental/ ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
                loader: "awesome-typescript-loader",
                exclude: [ /node_modules/, /experimental/ ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [{
                    loader: "style-loader",
                    options: {
                        sourceMap: true
                    }
                }, {
                    loader: "css-loader",
                    options: {
                        sourceMap: true
                    }
                }, {
                    loader: "sass-loader",
                    options: {
                        sourceMap: true
                    }
                }]
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: plugins
};
```

I'm using the following versions:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.0.0-beta.18",
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.0",
    "html5-history-api": "^4.2.7",
    "mocha": "^3.2.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.2",
    "nodemon": "^1.11.0",
    "nyc": "^10.1.2",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.14",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.3",
    "sequelize-auto": "^0.4.25",
    "sinon": "^2.0.0-pre.5",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.2.1",
    "sourcemap-istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "^0.2.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.16.1",
    "supertest": "^3.0.0",
    "tmp": "0.0.31",
    "ts-node": "^3.0.2",
    "tslib": "^1.6.0",
    "tslint": "^5.1.0",
    "tslint-loader": "^3.5.2",
    "typedoc": "^0.5.10",
    "typedoc-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.4",
    "typescript": "^2.2.2",
    "webpack": "^2.3.3",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.2",
    "webpack-visualizer-plugin": "^0.1.10",
    "xlsx": "^0.9.10",
    "yargs": "^7.0.2"
  }
```

## Update 1 (Added tsconfig.json)

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "lib": ["es6", "dom", "dom.iterable"],
        "downlevelIteration" : true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "jsx": "react",
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": false,
        "noImplicitThis": true,
        "baseUrl": "src",
    },
    "exclude": [
        "./node_modules"
    ]
}
```

Comment: This is awesome. Could you please share your tsconfig.json file as well?

Comment: I have added the tsconfig.json file as well

Answer (score 0):

have you tried setting `isolatedModules : true` in your tsconfig? Read more here: http://weblogs.thinktecture.com/thomas/2016/05/tired-of-waiting-for-typescript-compilation.html

Comment: It is much quicker like that, but it's still 2 seconds. Maybe there is somethnig wrong with my gulp file... Or is that a good time? It is very annoying when I go to the browser, refresh it and see that it hasn't changed :/

Comment: It is around 2.5sec for me too on an ~5k LOC project

Comment: browser refresh: you may consider using node-livereload as your webserver, so your browser is auto-reloaded when your target js file changes