# Is there an option in the tsconfig to compile a server and client to a public and private folder?

Tags: typescript, tsc, parcel

I have a typescript project and I have the following file structure

```
builds
-dev
--public
--private
-production
--public
--private

src
-server
-client

tsconfig
package.json
```

I want my src/server to compile to the private folders in build and the src/client to the public folders. I'm using Parcel as my compiler which uses the tsc. So my question is, can this be done with the compiler options of a single tsconfig. Because I noticed that you can only specify 1 output directory. Or would I have to make 2 tsconfigs in the server and client directory and somehow use both?

All the examples I could find were done with Webpack and I'm really set on using Parcel. 
[Server & client-side TypeScript project organization, compilation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43571111/server-client-side-typescript-project-organization-compilation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following requires *at least* typescript version 3.0 in order to create a composite build.

See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html

You will use two tsconfigs: one in `src/server` and one in `src/client`; You will also need a root `tsconfig.json`.

In the root you will need:

```
"references": [{
    "path": "./src/client"
}, {
    "path": "./src/server"
}]
```

Then in `src/client/tsconfig.json` you will need the following:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../../builds/dev/public",
    "rootDir": ".",
    "composite": true
}
```

Do the same for `server`.

Now when you run `tsc --build`, from the root directory, each of the subprojects will be built and placed in their respective outputs. Imports and exports will work as if everything existed in one project.

See [`project-references-demo`](https://github.com/RyanCavanaugh/project-references-demo) project for complete example.

Comment: That works but now it's tsc that compiles it. How about Parcel, do I even need that then?

Comment: @Michael, I'm not sure how to apply `parcel` to this because I've never used it. I was answering with respect to how to achieve this seperation using tsconfig and typescript. I think applying it to parcel will depend on what you use parcel for. Seeing as typescript will just produce js, I think parcel can help with bundling all the js into one file, or splitting it into multiple files to optimize the speed.